# Change view JQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I'm just trying to get the value of an array obtained by $each and change the view. The other view must contains the text that I selected on the other view and print it. I think i need to compair the values but i don't know how.

The HTML of the titles listview

```
<div class="example-wrapper" data-iscroll>
  <ul data-role="listview"  id="listados" > 
  </ul>
</div>
```

HTML of the content view

```
<div data-role="page" id="hcabecera">
  <div id="noticia">
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm getting the api of www.healthcare.gov/api/blog.json

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#home', function() {
  $.getJSON('https://www.healthcare.gov/api/blog.json', function(datos) {
    $.each(datos.blog, function(i, value) {
      if (value.lang == 'es') {
        $('#listados').append('<li><a>' + value.title + '</li></a>');
        $('#listados').listview('refresh');
      }
    });
    $("#listados li").on('click', function() {
      $.mobile.changePage("#hcabecera", {
        transition: "slide",
        changeHash: false
      });
      $("#noticia").append(datos.blog.content);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reworked your code into a working solution: https://jsfiddle.net/ss77uvsp/3/

You need to iterate in a slightly different way in order to collect the information you need. Then, after each iteration, evaluate the results and append to list. This is at least one way to do it.

For the "hcabecera" page, you need to find a way to link each title to the corresponding text. I suggest to append and hide all content in one go, and then display the requestet content basen on identification tags.

```
var title = "", lang = "", content = "", id = 1;

$.getJSON('https://www.healthcare.gov/api/blog.json', function(datos) {
  $.each(datos.blog, function() {
    $.each(this, function(i, value) {
      //The title appears before the language tag, so we need to save it temporarily
      if(i == "title")
        title = value;
      //Language
      if(i == "lang")
        lang = value;
      //Content
      if(i == "content")
        content = value;
    });
    //Check that the language is correct
    if(lang == "en"){
      //Append title to list
      $('#listados').append('<li data-no="'+id+'"><a>' + title + '</li></a>');
      //Append content to page hcabecera
      $("#noticia").append('<div id="item-'+id+'" class="items">'+content+'</div>');
      id++;
    }
  });
  //Refresh list
  $('#listados').listview('refresh');

  //List item click event
  $("#listados li").on('click', function() {
    //Get div ID
    var no = $(this).attr("data-no");
    $(".items").hide();
    $("#item-"+no).show();
    $.mobile.changePage("#hcabecera", {
      transition: "slide",
      changeHash: false
    });
  });
});
```